# Python Mac OS X not loading in external XML file when it is an app

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

I have a Python3 script that loads the file *parameters/parameters.xml*. The script is built into an app with PyInstaller. Started up the following ways, the script and app work fine:
  - Windows command line
  - Windows double click in explorer
  - Mac OS X command line

When starting the app from OS X Finder it is not able to find XML file.

Code snipped that calls the file:

```
try:
    self.paramTree = ET.parse("../parameters/parameters.xml")
except:
    self.paramTree = ET.parse("parameters/parameters.xml")
self.paramRoot = self.paramTree.getroot()
```

How could I make it so that the file is always loaded from the location of the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access a file through a relative path. It looks like the current working directory is not set in the same way in your last case (OS X Finder): this would cause the file to not be found.

You can therefore set the working directory based on the location of your program:

```
import os

# __file__ is a relative path to the program file (relative to the current
# working directory of the Python interpreter).
# Therefore, dirname() can yield an empty string,
# hence the need for os.path.abspath before os.chdir() is used:
prog_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
os.chdir(prog_dir)  # Sets the current directory
```

You might set the current working directory to something a bit different from this, depending on what the script expects (maybe the parent directory of the script: `os.path.join(prog_dir, os.pardir)`).

This should even remove the need for doing `try`: since the script uses paths relative to the current working directory, the current directory should instead be set first.

Comment: __file__ just gives the file name in python 3, fixed it by adding the function os.path.abspath

Comment: `abspath()` should indeed be used (I fixed the answer). However, `__file__` does give a _path to_ (not the name of) the program, _relative to the current working directory_ (this is why in some circumstances one may think that it gives only the program file name). Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy, section "Modules".